# Satchmo: list all active products

Tags: django, satchmo

I'd like to list all active products (from all or a specific category) in a template. I've looked almost everywhere and I simply cannot find a way to do this.

I want to display them in the footer of the shop (10 products from 1 category). That means show them without selecting product category.

Is this even possible? Products are only listed in the category template...

I'm using Satchmo 0.9.2

EDIT: Somehow I've missed this:
http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/customization.html

So it's solved...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is a more general answer since there isnt any answer yet, so dont beat me. You also have to know that I never used satchmo, I never had a look at it.

But despite this, if I had to deal with your situation, I would have a look at the source code.
You might find answers there to develop something custom for your situation. This can be a tricky task but at least its worth a try.

There have to be models which store the data for your product and categories. Have a look at them and the views that retrieve the products from the database to render them. Also a look into the database cant hurt (think of phpmyAdmin to have a nice webbased interface).

It can be helpful to fire up your ./manage.py shell, import your/satchmos product and category models and play around with them.

A possible solution then could be to write a custom context_processor which retrieves the needed products/categories and passes these products from a category to your footer on a more global basis. Have a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors. Maybe a custom middleware could also be a possibility. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

I hope this helps. At least worth a try :)

Comment: Hi, I know I'm looking for an easy fix... I don't want to break things... I've been doing exactly what you've suggested, especially the satchmo_category.py which list the categories and products... but I've not succeeded in modifying it the right way...